# Beginning a new, quick http request while a long running one is in progress

Tags: c#, httpclient

As per the title, I have a long running GET request executing and need to execute small, quick ones while waiting for a response for the long one. Unfortunately, the quick requests seem to have to wait for the long running one to execute before they are allowed to execute. If it helps to visualize, this is a web service taking requests that it is relaying to another web service and returning the results back to it's client so they can come in pretty much however and whenever the client is firing them.

I have tried using the same httpclient, different httpclients, I have tried changing HttpClientHandler.MaxConnectionsPerServer and ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit and nothing seems to do it. I have seen the solutions using WhenAll, etc but that doesn't work here because the small requests are coming in after the long running one has long since started and "WhenAll-ed".

I created a test app that is a simple windows form to troubleshoot this, it looks pretty much like this (with button clicks to simulate web requests being received):

```
    CookieContainer CookieContainer = null;
    MyClient myClient;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;

        myClient = new MyClient(ref CookieContainer);
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        bool success = await myClient.GetStockItemTables();
        this.label1.Text = success.ToString();
    }

    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        bool success = await myClient.GetGiftCardBalance();
        this.label2.Text = success.ToString();
    }


class MyClient
{
    string EndpointURL = @"XXX";
    private HttpClient Client;
    private HttpClientHandler ClientHandler;       

    public MyClient(ref CookieContainer cookieContainer)
    {
        try
        {
            bool loginRequired = false;                

            if (cookieContainer == null)
            {
                loginRequired = true;
                cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                //clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = true, CookieContainer = new CookieContainer() };
            }

            ClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { UseCookies = true, CookieContainer = cookieContainer, MaxConnectionsPerServer = 10 };

            Client = new HttpClient(ClientHandler)
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(EndpointURL),
                DefaultRequestHeaders =
                {
                    Accept = {MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("text/json")}
                },
                Timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(1)
            };

            if (loginRequired)               
                DoLogin(false);                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
    public async Task<bool> LongRunningRequest()
    {

        try
        {                
            var result = await Client.GetAsync(EndpointURL + "YYY");

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public async Task<bool> QuickRequest()
    {

        try
        {                
            var result = await Client.GetAsync(EndpointURL + "ZZZ");

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The CookieContainer is passed in/out to maintain login info and Login method excluded because it works and it isn't really relevant to the issue. The result of clicking button 1 then button 2 is code getting 'stuck' at the quick requests 'PostAsync' until the long requests 'GetAsync' completes. Same results if each call uses it's own MyClient instead of sharing a global one. Help?

Comment: What are the await doing?

Comment: See answer. It was the web service blocking concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

So looks like it wasn't me or the code. The web service I am using was blocking concurrent requests from the same session. Changing the quick request to just do a 'get' from google evaluates immediately and is not blocked, as expected. Looks like the solution is to create a second session for these quick calls so they aren't blocked if we are in the middle of a long request.